# Use split part to parse a string in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a sample data set with following three values for `colnew`;

```
|         colnew                      |    id.  |
|        :-----:                      |  :----: |
| Requote reason:Other                |   1     |
| Additional details:Incoterms change |         |
  - - - - - - - - - -  - - - - - - - --  - - - - -
|Additional details:origin agent error|   2     |
  - - - - -  - - - - - - - - - - -  - - - - - - - -      
|      origin agent change            |   3     |
```

The goal is to parse the values  of `colnew` so that, we have following expected output.

**Expected Output**

```
| colnew                               | reason          | additional details|  id.  |
| :----------------------------------: |  :------------: | :--------:  |
                                      |  Other          |  Incoterms change  |  1   |
|Requote reason: Other.               |                 |
|Additional details: Incoterms change |                 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Additional details: origin agent error | None          | origin agent error |. 2   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| origin agent change                 | origin agent change | None. | 
  3     |
```

Here is my attemot in sql;

```sql
select 
split_part(colnew, ':', 2) as reason
from table
```

But this is giving us only partial output. Please see screenshot for actual output.

```
| colnew                           | reason                   |
-----------------------------------  -------------------------
| Requote reason: Other            | Other Additional details |
|Additional details: Incoterms change |                        |
-------------------------------------- ---------------------
| Additional details: origin agent error |  origin agent error  |
----------------------------------------  ----------------------
| origin agent change                    | NULL                 |
```

Kindly advise on how to get the expected output. thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi - please format your data as tables so it is easier to understand what’s in each column/row. The actual output column names don’t match the SQL, please update your question to ensure all the information is consistent - as at the moment it’s a bit confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your input comes in a variety of forms, `SPLIT_PART` won't be sufficient. Using [Snowflake’s `REGEXP_SUBSTR`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_substr_all) to handle all 3 scenarios correctly should get you what you want:

```
SELECT 
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(colnew, "^(Requote reason\s?:\s?)?(.+)$", 1, 1, "cme", 2) as reason,
    COALESCE(
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(colnew, "^Additional details\s?:\s?(.+)$", 1, 1, "cme", 1),
        'None.'
    ) as "additional details"
FROM table
```

Comment: thanks for response. Can you kindly share some output what you are seeing?
Because for me above query is giving following error;

`100048 (2201B): Invalid regular expression: '^(?:Requote reasons?:s?)?(.+)$', no argument for repetition operator: ?`

Comment: @jay Separate from the error you're calling out, how are you invoking this code? Whatever that method is seems to be interpreting the escape characters `\ ` before passing the query text to Snowflake. You'll have to manage that on your own by re-escaping each of the `\ ` manually or properly restricting this behavior in the invoking language, especially since you haven't provided any context to that end in your question.

Comment: @jay The error itself is relating to the fact I forgot Snowflake does not support non-capturing groups (as of this writing, anyway). I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: that helps @esqew.
One help I need. if the text says `origin agent change`, is it possible to get the value for reason as `None`. since this text doesn't contain the words `Requote Reason`.
May I now how can we modify the present regex to achieve this. thanx in advance.

Comment: @jay You should be able to gate the first component of the `SELECT` above with a `CASE` statement to handle such a situation. `CASE WHEN colnew = 'origin agent change' THEN 'None' ELSE...`